# Is the military balance of South Asia dependent only on US-made weapons?

Tags: united-states, india, pakistan

According to the following article -

- [US Approves To Sustain Pakistan’s F-16 Fighter Jet Fleet; To Reverse Trump-Era Suspension Of Security Assistance](https://eurasiantimes.com/us-approves-to-sustain-pakistans-f-16-fighter-jet-fleet-to-reverse/)

> The US Defense Security Cooperation Agency (DSCA) notified Congress on September 7 of the State Department’s decision to approve the possible Foreign Military Sale to Pakistan of F-16 Case for Sustainment and related equipment for an estimated cost of US $450 million.
>
> The proposed sale does not include any new capabilities, weapons, or munitions and will not alter the military balance in the region.

My question is, how does the USA determine the military balance of South Asia? Is it only based on US-made platforms?

If Pakistan, say, purchased 250 [J10c jet fighters](https://eurasiantimes.com/pakistans-most-capable-fighter-chinese-origin-j-10c-jet-gets-mirage/) from China and/or purchased 250 [Akinci heavy UAVs](https://eurasiantimes.com/turkeys-fully-loaded-baykar-akinci-combat-drone-completes-test-flight-armed-with-all-weapon-stations/) from Turkey. In that case, would the USA still sell that F-16 related equipment to Pakistan?

Comment: "wouldn't that alter the military balance of South Asia" Yes, but nobody knows how much. The question could be too speculative.

Answer (score 3):

> Is the military balance of South Asia dependent only on US-made
> weapons?

No.

South Asia looks to multiple countries to supply weapons.

Also, both India and Pakistan, at least, both have significant domestic defense industries.

One of [India's aircraft carriers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INS_Vikramaditya), for example, is predominantly Russian sourced. [Another of its aircraft carriers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INS_Vikrant_(2013)) was built domestically (and carries Russian jet fighters, Russian military helicopters, American military helicopters, and domestically made military helicopters).

Another question at Politics.SE noted that Pakistan manufactures much of its own ammunition.

China makes 80% of Bangladesh's military equipment.

Multiple countries in South Asia have purchased military systems from countries in addition to the United States, and essentially all of them are open to doing so in the future if the terms are right.